# Can a User/Non-Moderator see deleted chat messages?

Tags: support, chat

Can a user who is not a Moderator see the deleted chat messages from other users?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes: In addition to moderators and the originally posting user, the room owners (of the particular room) also have access to the history of deleted messages.

However, unless the message's `(removed)` stub is right there visible in the chat room (in which case you can click "history"), you'll have to manipulate URLs by hand. This is intentionally designed to be not too simple a process.

Nobody else can see them, though. In particular, this is *not* related to reputation (unlike the ability to see deleted *rooms*).

Comment: The history link is only shown if `i || users[c].is_moderator`. I can't tell what `i` is, but it's still undefined even if you're the post/room owner

Comment: @TimStone `i` is `isMine` (as in, it's a message by the active user). Yeah, that's incosistent, I'll fix that.

Comment: Ok, so the room owner can see the deleted messages from history. Thanks.

Comment: What if the message is moved to other room? Can one who is RO in the source room and not in the target chat room still see it when it's deleted?

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard I don't know for certain off the top of my head, but likely not.